# VBA Automation error when querying database through ODBC

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, odbc

I am trying to run Excel macro to query some data from my ODBC database.
My database details are as below:

**DSN**: `sgdv`    **UID**:`l8qc1`   **Password**:`l8qc1`   **server**:`sgdv`

I am trying to query the data from the database but the VBA shows the error as below for the line `Connection.Open "DSN=sgdv"`.

*Run-time error -2147217843 (80040e4d) Automation error*

I can't identify the error. Please help. Below is my code

```
Sub ReadDB()
Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim intRowCounter
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
intRowCounter = 2
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:Z100").Clear
Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.Open "DSN=sgdv"
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM DEDICT01 where DEDICT01.SER_SN='Z1E80R4C'"
Set resultSet = Connection.Execute(strQuery)
Do While Not resultSet.EOF
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & intRowCounter).Value = resultSet.Fields("DEDICT01.CUST_PARTS_NO").Value
  resultSet.movenext
Loop
resultSet.Close
End Sub
```

---

I have modified the program and my new coding is

```
Sub ReadDB()
Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
Dim intRowCounter
Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
intRowCounter = 2
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:Z100").Clear
Set Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.ConnectionString = "DSN=sgdv;UID=l8qc1;PWD=l8qc1;"
Connection.Open
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM DEDICT01 where DEDICT01.SER_SN='Z1E80R4C'"
Set resultSet = Connection.Execute(strQuery)
Do While Not resultSet.EOF
    mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & intRowCounter).Value = resultSet.Fields("DEDICT01.CUST_PARTS_NO").Value
  resultSet.movenext
Loop
resultSet.Close
End Sub
```

My Previous error is gone but now I am getting new error at the line

```
mainWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & intRowCounter).Value = resultSet.Fields("DEDICT01.CUST_PARTS_NO").Value
```

The error is

**Run-Time error '3265':**

**Application-defined or Object-defined error**

Comment: What line is generating the error?

Comment: I don't know how to see which line gives error...

Comment: In the VBA Editor window, place the cursor somewhere in the code for this sub and press F8. This will step into your code one line at a time. Just press F8 until you get an error. Note the line that you were on when the error message popped up.

Comment: I did as you said @Excellll. In VBA Editor I kept pressing **F8**. The Line `Connection.Open "DSN=sgdv"` got highlighted as yellow. When I pressed the **F8** at this line after being highlighted the error code shows up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your connection string. Note that you mentioned UID, password, etc. information in your question, but this info appears nowhere in your code. To connect to the database, you must supply this information in the connection string.

Try the following:

```
Connection.ConnectionString = "DSN=sgdv;UID=l8qc1;PWD=l8qc1;"
Connection.Open
```

I can't guarantee this will work, but it should at least get you on the right track. If it doesn't work, you may need to tweak the connection string. For more information about ADODB connections and connection strings, see this MSDN page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx

Answer (score -2):

The answer depends on what you mean with `mainworkbook`

- if it is another workbook you need to give complete path like c:......
- if it is current workbook there is no need to select the datatype. The current workbook itself is the active workbook

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: As you can see from the other comments, your answer is not easy to understand. I'll edit it to include some punctuation and make it clearer what I think you want to say.